# Dragging a Grid and increasing its width

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

How can I drag a Grid element in Windows Phone 8.1 and increase its width according to the distance it's being dragged? Say I have a `50px` wide grid element and I drag it to `400px` location on the screen; I want it to scale accordingly, and with the same speed as it is dragged.

I'm trying to create a storyboard for this and I'm able to manipulate the width, but how can I vary the speed of animation to match the speed of dragging? Also, how do I make the width dependent on the location of the pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use the Storyboard. See code below.

XAML:

```
   <Grid x:Name="FlippedGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ManipulationMode="TranslateX" ManipulationDelta="FlippedGridOnManipulationDelta"  Width="60" Height="100" Background="Aquamarine"/>
```

Do not forget to set ManipulationMode!

CS:

```
private void FlippedGridOnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var delta = e.Delta.Translation.X;

    FlippedGrid.Width += delta;

    //TODO If you want check position, retrieve e.Position:
    //var position = e.Position;

    //TODO If you want change flip velocity
    //double velocity = 1.5;
    //FlippedGrid.Width += delta * velocty;
 }
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out and ended up using this only. Thanks